# X509Certificate2.Verify() returns true in console app, false in asp.net web app

Tags: azure, x509certificate

I've a feeling it's something to do with the permissions of the AppPool but as this app is hosted in Azure it's not possible to change that.

My code works in a console app and when the AppPool is set to run as a user (myself). It fails to run when the AppPool is set to run as ApplicationIdentity and when the service is hosted in Azure (I'll post the code if requested, but I don't think that's where the problem lies).

It doesn't matter whether I load the certificate from a store, from a file, or from a byte array. The results are the same.

I don't know what information will be helpful in diagnosing this but it appears that the chain/path doesn't load under the reduced privileges. Calling .Verify() returns true in the console app (and IIS running as my user) and false under ApplicationIdentity.

The certificate appears to load normally and contains a private key in both circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out my problem was the same listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277791/x509certificate2-validation-on-web-service). I needed to set my certificates up so that some of them were in the CA and Trust section so that the chain was built correctly.

I had all of the certificates installed but it would appear that the location of the certificate is important as well, and it was nothing to do with security or which user was logged on at all!

Answer (score 0):

You can change almost anything in Azure. It is full IIS (if you are not upgrading from SDK 1.3 or earlier) by default. There are couple of options to try:

1. **(This one is wrong! Noted by Steve Marx)***Try jus trunning the application (in this case IIS AppPool) in Elevated mode. That will make AppPool running under "SYSTEM" account, instead of AppPoolIdentity. You can do that by adding a [<runtime executionContext="elevated" />](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg557553.aspx) element in your role definition in .CSDEF file.*
2. You can enable remote desktop to all your roles. That will effectively create an account in your role instance and add it to the Administrators group. Then you can use a startup task and powershell script to change AppPool identity to use that account instead: [A blog post by Wade Wegner on how to programatically change AppPool Identity](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/01/programmatically-changing-the-apppool-identity-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/).

Well, these all are ways to make your application pool runs in Elevated mode, but also show that you can do pretty much everything with IIS on your Windows Azure Instance. I suggest to use site runing in elevated mode only for testing purposes. First make your code run in restricted account on local IIS. Then see what you changed to make it wokrk locally and apply these changes on the Azure Web Role.

**EDIT**

Another thing to pay attention is that in order .Verify() to work, you must have the Root Certificate of the CA that issued the checked certificate, installed on the web role. This can be done via adding the Root CA Certificate as a "Service Certificate" from the management portal. Also, the CA that issued the checked certificated must be trusted.

Comment: #1 is wrong. Running a web role elevated has no effect on the identity used for the app pool. (IIS will still use Network Service.) It only changes the identity used to run the RoleEntryPoint code.

Comment: I think the most likely issue is the trust chain of the cert is broken as you mention.  On your local machine, open the certificate in the certificate manager and check the Certificate Path tab, it will show something above cert. RDP into the azure machine and check the same, it will likely be missing the CA or a variation thereof.